# Update object property value with modified array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm aware I can use `$.extend` to merge to objects. What if I want to merge/update an array into an existing array, which is teh value of one of the properties of an object?

`Obj = {id: 63, region: "place", shops: Array[246]}`

`$.extend(true, Obj.traits, amendedShopsArray)` `// Doesnt work`

to return `Obj = {id: 63, region: "place", amendedShopsArray: Array[246]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second key to the object with the same data, and then [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the one you do not want:

```js
// shops mocked for simplicity
var obj = {id: 63, region: 'place', shops: [1, 2, 3]};

obj.amendedShopsArray = obj.shops;
delete obj.shops;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.extend` will not merge arrays, you can use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like this:

```
var newArray = [.....];
Obj.shops = Obj.shops.concat(newArray);
```

If you want to change the property name:

```
var newArray = [.....];
Obj.amendedShopsArray = Obj.shops.concat(newArray);
delete Obj.shops;
```